# Submit button taking 2 clicks on a php form

Tags: php, form-submit

Hi I'm new to trying to do a delete button using PHP & DABL.

When  I click the delete button it deletes it from the DB but still shows on the page.

If I refresh the page or click the button again it removes it.

I know i'm doing something wrong but not sure what.

Many Thanks

Mark

```
<?php
require_once('includes/header.php');
$loginTypes = LoginTypes::getAll();

<ul>
    <?php foreach ($loginTypes as $loginType){?>
    <li><?php echo $loginType->type; $LoginTypeId = $loginType->login_type_id; ?>
        <form action ="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method='post' >
        <input type='hidden' name='<?php echo $LoginTypeId; ?>' id='<?php echo $LoginTypeId; ?>' /> 
        <input type='submit' name='submit_<?php echo $LoginTypeId; ?>' id="submit_<?php echo $LoginTypeId; ?>" value='delete' />
         </form>
     </li>
            <?php if(isset($_POST["submit_$LoginTypeId"])){
                    $delete = LoginTypes::retrieveByPK("$LoginTypeId");
                    $delete->delete(); 
                    }} ?>
</ul>
<?php require_once('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly modified version of Alex Ciminian's code.

Main changes are where you are dealing with the POST variable. This should work, but obviously I can't really test it without having your logintypes class at my disposal.

Since they are all in different forms you don't need to use a unique name for the submit button (or the delete id hidden field). I'd still be tempted to improve the code by putting it all in one form and have checkboxes to mark which ones you want to delete, but this should suffice for now.

```
<?php
require_once('includes/header.php');
if(isset($_POST['deleteSubmit'])) {
  $delete = LoginTypes::retrieveByPK($_POST['LoginTypeId']);
  $delete->delete(); 
}
$loginTypes = LoginTypes::getAll();
?>

<ul>
    <?php
    foreach ($loginTypes as $loginType){ ?>
    <li><?php echo $loginType->type; $LoginTypeId = $loginType->login_type_id; ?>
        <form action ="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method='post' >
        <input type='hidden' name='LoginTypeId' value='<?php echo $LoginTypeId; ?>' id='<?php echo $LoginTypeId; ?>' /> 
        <input type='submit' name='deleteSubmit' id="submit_<?php echo $LoginTypeId; ?>" value='delete' />
         </form>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
<?php require_once('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Nick's right, I didn't pay much attention to the values of the variables. I looked more at the logic flow.

Comment: Just seen this, I got it sorted but thank you for taking the time to reply

Answer (score 2):

Because you display the item before you actually delete it. Put the `if` before the `foreach`.

Try this:

```
<?php
require_once('includes/header.php');
?>

<ul>
    <?php 

    if(isset($_POST["submit_$LoginTypeId"])) {
        $delete = LoginTypes::retrieveByPK("$LoginTypeId");
        $delete->delete(); 
    }    
    $loginTypes = LoginTypes::getAll();
    foreach ($loginTypes as $loginType){ ?>
    <li><?php echo $loginType->type; $LoginTypeId = $loginType->login_type_id; ?>
        <form action ="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method='post' >
        <input type='hidden' name='<?php echo $LoginTypeId; ?>' id='<?php echo $LoginTypeId; ?>' /> 
        <input type='submit' name='submit_<?php echo $LoginTypeId; ?>' id="submit_<?php echo $LoginTypeId; ?>" value='delete' />
         </form>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
<?php require_once('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you I tried this earlier and thought I was doing it wrong, as I then get that $LoginTypeId is an undefined variable as it isn't defined until after the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

You should perform delete action before

```
$loginTypes = LoginTypes::getAll();
```